# Unable to import module 'charge': Error : netlify functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

i did this gatsby and netlify.

https://www.thedigitalsages.com/creating-charges-for-stripe-with-react-and-netlify-functions-part-1/

but but I am getting this error.

```
Unable to import module 'charge': Error
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/charge.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

checkoutForm.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {injectStripe} from 'react-stripe-elements';
import axios from 'axios';
import AddressSection from './AddressSection';
import CardSection from './CardSection';
import {Button} from 'reactstrap';
import Success from './Success';
import './form-css.css'

class CheckoutForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: undefined,
      email: undefined,
      address: undefined,
      city: undefined,
      state: undefined,
      program: undefined,
      price: undefined,
      success: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const name = event.target.name
    this.setState({[name]: event.target.value});
  }


  handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();

    this.props.stripe.createToken({
        name: this.state.name,
        address_city: this.state.city,
        address_line1: this.state.address,
        address_state: this.state.state,
        address_country: "US"
      }).then(({token}) =>
      {
        const charge = JSON.stringify({
          token,
          charge: {
            amount: 2000,
            currency: 'usd',
            email: this.state.email,
            number: this.state.number
          },
        })
        axios.post('/.netlify/functions/charge', charge)
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="form-css" className="w-100">
        { this.state.success === false ?
          <div>
            <AddressSection handleChange={this.handleChange} schedule={this.state.schedule} />
            <CardSection />
          </div>
          :
          <Success />
        }
        <Button className="w-100 h4">Pay $50</Button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
```

charge.js folder / function/charge.js and working on netlify function.

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("....");
var axios = require('axios');

module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  const requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const token = requestBody.token.id;
  const amount = requestBody.charge.amount;
  const currency = requestBody.charge.currency;
  const email = requestBody.charge.email;

  return stripe.charges.create({ // Create Stripe charge with token
    amount,
    currency,
    receipt_email: email,
    description: 'Serverless Stripe Test charge',
    source: token,
  })
    .then((charge) => { // Success response
      const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: `Charge processed succesfully!`,
          charge,
        }),
      };
      callback(null, response);
    })
    .catch((err) => { // Error response
      const response = {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          error: err.message,
        }),
      };
      callback(null, response);
    })
};
```

i think axios errors /:

https://reverent-meitner-8da20d.netlify.com/ demo link thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda/issues/66

Check out the above thread. I was having similar issues to you and yarn add/npm install babel-loader fixed things for me - hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Axios post takes an object as data, you are passing it a string.

`axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`

So if you remove the `JSON.stringify` done on the charge object you are creating maybe that will fix your problem.